# Select all from Table Set one column to alias with AS

Tags: sql-server

I have a query that selects all from about five tables and joins them all together.
The issue is that each of the tables has two column names that are the same across all the tables. I want to select all the data, but I want to tie these two columns in as a different name than what is given to them.

My Query looks like this currently:

```
select updatedInfo.*,
                nameInfo.*,
                addressInfo.*,
                phoneInfo.*,
                emailInfo.*,
                positionInfo.*
                from updatedInfo join nameInfo on updatedInfo.IndivId=nameInfo.nameInfoId
                      join addressInfo on updatedInfo.IndivId=addressInfo.addressInfoId
                      join emailInfo on updatedInfo.IndivId=emailInfo.emailInfoId
                      join phoneInfo on updatedInfo.IndivId=phoneInfo.phoneInfoId
                      join positionInfo on updatedInfo.IndivId=positionInfo.IndivId
                      where updatedInfo.correctedInFNV is not null
                      order by updatedInfo.IndivId
```

The column names are `updated` and `alreadyCorrect`. **Updated** notes that the information has been updated in some way, and **AlreadyCorrect** denotes that the information was correct when sent for update.

Can I do something like this?

```
select updatedInfo.*,
       nameInfo.*, nameInfo.updated as nameUpdated .....
```

would that work? or would I have to list every column on the table? Would this take both the un-renamed column **AND** the aliased one?

Comment: You really should not be using select * anyway. Do you really use every single column from every table?

Comment: I do use every single column from every table. It's a very lean schema. The tables only have at most ten columns.

Comment: So be explicit and name the columns. This is how you should write all your queries anyway. And if you have 10 columns this means your query here is 60 columns. And if you change the schema you are returning more data than you need.

Comment: this is a small app, and I appreciate the sentiment. I will take this into consideration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your alternative would not work as you would still have the old column name in it (as you are selecting with * ). In result you would have the "Updated" column twice. Once with the name "Updated" and once with "nameUpdated".

The only solution is to list every column and give them an alias if necessary.

Alternative:
You can create a temporary/hash table where you give your column a different name, then using the select from your question to insert all the data and in the end you just do `Select * from tempTable`

Comment: Thanks for this, having both the original and the alias are acceptable to me. Thanks for the confirmation!